# How to check whether a user is having access permission for a file or not in Axapta X++?

Tags: file, axapta, x++

How to check whether a user is having  access permission for a file or not in Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2009 with X++?

Answer (score 0):

FileIoPermission class is used to ensure that the code has access to a file before performing any IO. Here is the code sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa625136%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

The following code example shows a new instance of the FileIoPermission class that specifies read access for the File.txt file.

The assert method is called to declare that the code can then call the AsciiIo.new method.

```
server static void main(Args args)
{
    FileIoPermission _perm;
    AsciiIo a;

    ;

    _perm = new FileIoPermission("c:\\File.txt",'r');
    _perm.assert();

    // Invoke the protected API.
    a = new AsciiIo("c:\\File.txt",'r');
}
```